# How can i hide a div with a specific class that contains a link with a specific href using a CSS / CSS3 selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

i want to add a style (display:none) to hide a div element with the class "xclass" but only if it contains a link with the href "/somedir/somepage.php" is this doable with CSS or CSS3 selectors?

below is some example code for the div i wish to hide, it could appear anywhere inside a web page.

```
<div class="xclass">
  <div>
    <div>
     <a href="/somedir/somepage.php">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this isn't possible. Due to the way browsers handle CSS selectors, you cannot select a parent element based on its children.

This might be doable with JavaScript. Here's a jQuery snippet:

```
$('.xclass').each(function() {
    if ($(this).has('a[href="/somedir/somepage.php"]')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: ok thanks, though i was looking for a css only solution, unfortunately. the jquery code looks interesting though, have not used jquery before, might investigate. cheers.